# Power Management only has the option of "Do Nothing" for critically low battery in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, power-management

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome on an Asus laptop.

In the Power Settings interface, under the Power tab, there is an option at the bottom to set what to do in case the battery gets critically low.

However, when I click on the drop down to set that option, it only offers one option, which is "do nothing":

[image: do nothing power option]

Currently, my laptop will run down to 0 battery power, or close to it, and then shut off with no warnings, no possibility of closing programs and shutting down gracefully.

I would like to have a warning when the battery is at 10% and hopefully some time to manually save and shut down programs before turning the computer off. How do I achieve this?

---

Edit: Here is the contents of my `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` file:

```
# Only the system vendor should modify this file, ordinary users
# should not have to change anything.

[UPower]

# Enable the Watts Up Pro device.
#
# The Watts Up Pro contains a generic FTDI USB device without a specific
# vendor and product ID. When we probe for WUP devices, we can cause
# the user to get a perplexing "Device or resource busy" error when
# attempting to use their non-WUP device.
#
# The generic FTDI device is known to also be used on:
#
# - Sparkfun FT232 breakout board
# - Parallax Propeller
#
# default=false
EnableWattsUpPro=false

# Don't poll the kernel for battery level changes.
#
# Some hardware will send us battery level changes through
# events, rather than us having to poll for it. This option
# allows disabling polling for hardware that sends out events.
#
# default=false
NoPollBatteries=false

# Do we ignore the lid state
#
# Some laptops are broken. The lid state is either inverted, or stuck
# on or off. We can't do much to fix these problems, but this is a way
# for users to make the laptop panel vanish, a state that might be used
# by a couple of user-space daemons. On Linux systems, see also
# logind.conf(5).
#
# default=false
IgnoreLid=false

# Policy for warnings and action based on battery levels
#
# Whether battery percentage based policy should be used. The default
# is to use the time left, change to true to use the percentage, which
# should work around broken firmwares. It is also more reliable than
# the time left (frantically saving all your files is going to use more
# battery than letting it rest for example).
# default=true
UsePercentageForPolicy=true

# When UsePercentageForPolicy is true, the levels at which UPower will
# consider the battery low, critical, or take action for the critical
# battery level.
#
# This will also be used for batteries which don't have time information
# such as that of peripherals.
#
# If any value is invalid, or not in descending order, the defaults
# will be used.
#
# Defaults:
# PercentageLow=10
# PercentageCritical=3
# PercentageAction=2
PercentageLow=10
PercentageCritical=3
PercentageAction=2

# When UsePercentageForPolicy is false, the time remaining at which UPower
# will consider the battery low, critical, or take action for the critical
# battery level.
#
# If any value is invalid, or not in descending order, the defaults
# will be used.
#
# Defaults:
# TimeLow=1200
# TimeCritical=300
# TimeAction=120
TimeLow=1200
TimeCritical=300
TimeAction=120

# The action to take when "TimeAction" or "PercentageAction" above has been
# reached for the batteries (UPS or laptop batteries) supplying the computer
#
# Possible values are:
# PowerOff
# Hibernate
# HybridSleep
#
# If HybridSleep isn't available, Hibernate will be used
# If Hibernate isn't available, PowerOff will be used
CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep
```

Comment: Check is this you ar looking for https://askubuntu.com/questions/92794/how-to-change-critically-low-battery-value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Step 1: Check `gsettings`

There are two options you can check in the terminal:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action
'suspend'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low
'10'
```

Then to change them use:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action suspend
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10
```

Note on my system they are just fine, so I changed them back to what they were in the first place for sake of example.

---

## Step 2: Check `upower`

Gnome power management utilizes `upower` to do the heavy lifting. To ensure it is running and collecting battery statistics as it should, use:

```
$ upower -d 
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
  native-path:          ACAD
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 18 Mar 2018 02:28:25 PM MDT (135878 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               COMPAL
  model:                PABAS0241231
  serial:               41167
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 20 Mar 2018 04:12:10 AM MDT (53 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              48.2544 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         93.3552 Wh
    energy-full-design:  96.48 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0044914 W
    voltage:             14.76 V
    percentage:          51%
    capacity:            96.7612%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-good-charging-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_0003o046Do101Ax0008
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:101A.0008
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                Performance MX
  serial:               E6CE4571
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Tue 20 Mar 2018 04:12:09 AM MDT (54 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          55%
    icon-name:          'battery-good-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/keyboard_0003o046Do2010x0009
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:2010.0009
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                K800
  serial:               6DB54BFE
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Tue 20 Mar 2018 04:12:09 AM MDT (54 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  keyboard
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          90%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/ups_hiddev3
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4/1-1.4.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev3
  vendor:               CPS
  model:                CP550HGa
  serial:               BFBB104#BI1.g
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 20 Mar 2018 04:12:51 AM MDT (12 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  ups
    present:             yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    time to empty:       37.5 minutes
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 20 Mar 2018 04:10:14 AM MDT (169 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  ups
    present:             yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    time to empty:       37.5 minutes
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

First run this command when the laptop is plugged in. Then unplug the laptop and run the command after some time and ensure battery remaining time has reduced appropriately.

---

## Last Step - Low level hibernation

This is the last step which would be taken after exhausting all other steps. This step doesn't require Ubuntu or Unity or Gnome or `gsettings` or `upower`. It only requires `systemd`, `udev` and `cron` which are built into almost all Linux Distros with or without GUI (Desktop).

From [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/laptop#hibernate_on_low_battery_level):

### Hibernate on low battery level

If your battery sends events to `udev` whenever it (dis)charges by 1%, you can use this `udev` rule to automatically hibernate the system when battery level is critical, and thus prevent all unsaved work from being lost.
**Note:** Not all batteries report discharge events. Test by running `udevadm monitor --property` while on battery and see if any events are reported. You should wait at least 1% drop. If no events are reported and `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/alarm` is non-zero then the battery will likely trigger an event when `BAT0/energy_now` drops below the alarm value, and the `udev` rule will work as long as the percentage math works out. Some laptops have an option for this disabled in BIOS by default.

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-lowbat.rules

# Suspend the system when battery level drops to 5% or lower
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="[0-5]", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate"
```

This rule will be repeated whenever the condition is set. As such, when resuming from hibernate when the battery is critical, the computer will hibernate directly. Some laptops do not boot beyond a certain battery level, so the rule could be adjusted accordingly.

Batteries can jump to a lower value instead of discharging continuously, therefore a `udev` string matching pattern for all capacities `0` through `5` is used.

Other rules can be added to perform different actions depending on power supply status and/or capacity.

If your system has no or missing ACPI events, use `cron` with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
acpi -b | awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | {
    read -r status capacity

    if [ "$status" = Discharging -a "$capacity" -lt 5 ]; then
        logger "Critical battery threshold"
        systemctl hibernate
    fi
}
```

### Testing events

One way to test `udev` rules is to have them create a file when they are run. For example:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/98-discharging.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /home/example/discharging"
```

This creates a file at `/home/example/discharging` when the laptop charger is unplugged. You can test whether the rule worked by unplugging your laptop and looking for this file. For more advanced `udev` rule testing, see [Udev#Testing rules before loading](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Testing_rules_before_loading).

## Summary

There are more steps to post between Step #2 and "Last Step" but these will be posted as OP reveals more details after testing. In the mean time the "Last Step" should reduce more half-way answers like simply reporting percentage remaining.

Comment: Thank you for this response. Unfortunately, it seems that my `gsettings` parameters were already set to `suspend` and `10`,  which would indicate that my system is not respecting those options.

Comment: @Questioner `gsettings` was the first (easy) step to check. I've added `upower` the next step to take.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I will test the laptop as you suggest. In the meantime, I've added the contents of my `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` file to my question.

Comment: @Questioner I ran `clipboard-diff` between your `UPower.conf` and the version installed on my system. They are identical.

Comment: @Questioner Couple questions: 1) Does `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active` return `true`? 2) Do you have a swap partition > amount of RAM?

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active` returns `true`. I have a swap partition that is 2X RAM (or more).  `udevadm monitor --property` does not return anything, even after the battery drops a few percent. Lastly, possibly as a result of running the gsettings commands in step one that I now get a popup warning from the battery icon in the gnome panel when my battery reaches 15%. However, the popup goes away in mere seconds, is easy to miss (maybe it was there before), and there is no record of it after the fact. Lastly, the laptop still does not hibernate or warn at 10%.

Comment: @Questioner The pop-up only lasts for about 5 to 10 seconds usually. This question has three answers that might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262723/wrong-battery-state-reading-cause-brutal-shutdown?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa Also I wonder if there might be a bug related to Asus. This isn't the bug but an example they do exist: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1661876 What is your ASUS model number?

Answer (score 3):

#### Heres a friendly script I put together!

I've created a makeshift solution that checks if your laptop is on AC or Battery (DC) power...

Therefore, if it is on AC power it will exit and if not it will continue checking the remaining battery power every 15 seconds until it hits the defined variable `low` or rather percent...

Oh and if you want to continue working in the same terminal as you ran this script as simply run the script like so:

```
bash power-notify.sh &
```

Without further ado, here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get battery percent
bat_percent=$(acpi | awk -F ", " '{print $2}' | tr -d %)


#When to start showing warnings... Example: 10% --> low=10
low=10
#Alert message to show when low percent is reached
alert="Low battery, $bat_percent% left..."

#Check if notify-send is installed
notfiy_send_test=$(which notify-send)
if [ $? != 0 ] 
then
    echo "Please install notify-send..."
    exit 1
fi

acpi_test=$(which acpi)
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "Please install acpi..."
    exit 1
fi


#Test if cord is plugged in 
plugged=$(acpi -a | awk -F ": " '{print $2}')

if [ $plugged == 'on-line' ]
then
    echo "Your computer is connected to a power source..."
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 0
fi

while :
do

    if [ $bat_percent -lt $low ]
    then
        notify-send "$alert"
        sleep 15
    else
        #Check every fifteen seconds to use less resources...
        sleep 15
    fi

done
```

This script can also be found on GitHub, [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NerdOfCode/Scripts/master/Bash/low_battery.sh)...

Comment: A working system is supposed to give warnings already at given percentages and then hybrid-sleep at 2%. I think that's what the OP is looking for. Your script could be improved by calling hibernate at 2%.  Also a warning bubble every 15 seconds is extreme IMO. A message bubble t 9%, 8%, 7%... 3% would be more practical I think. Also a system alert sound would help people not looking at their laptop at the time. This script has some of the components I recommended: https://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu/837115#837115

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix just a simple script

Comment: I guess both your script and my script I linked in the last comment can be considered simple by professionals. I'm not sure which script you are calling "simple" though?

Comment: My script definitely.

Comment: No it's a good script and does what you want it to do. All great scripts start out as good scripts and you can improve it over days, weeks or decades. Linux has been around for a long time and will be around for a lot longer.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix very motivational... thank you! Good to hear a second opinion on one of my creations.

Comment: Thank you for providing this script as an option. Is the idea that I would run it at a terminal command line every time I started my computer?

Comment: You could make a cronjob so it is automatically ran by itself

Comment: I am trying your script now. I actually prefer an aggressive warning system, with a message every percent starting from 20% and then forcing hibernate at 10%. I'll let you know how your script does.